# strikethrough text in a foreach?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 and C# for a small web application. Its use is for creating a simple to-do list. What I'm struggling with is that I've got a list of tasks displayed in a foreach. With each task is a checkbox, and basically when the checkbox is clicked (i.e true) then the text should have a strike through it. I tried to use Javascript but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr style="border: 1px solid;"> 
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="taskDone(@item.Id)" />
    </td>
    <td>
       <p id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskDetails)</p>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

and Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function taskDone(id) {
    var c = document.getElementById(id);
    if (this.checkbox.checked) {
        c.className = "strike";
    }
    else {
        c.className = "nostrike";
    }
}
</script>
```

and the bit of CSS:

```
.strike
{text-decoration: line-through;}
```

could someone explain where I'm going wrong. thanks

Comment: I think you should do `this.checked` instead of `this.checkbox.checked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `(this.checkbox.checked)` which does not refer the checkbox element

Pass the checkbox id `mychekbox` as second paramter into `taskDone()`, get that element and validate that it's checked or not by  `if(checkBox.checked)`,

```
<input id="mychekbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="taskDone(@item.Id, 'mychekbox')" />

function taskDone(id,  checkBoxId) {
    var c = document.getElementById(id);
    var  checkBox = document.getElementById(checkBoxId); //getting checkbox
    if (checkBox.checked) { //validating checked or not
        c.className = "strike";
    }
    else {
        c.className = "nostrike";
    }
}
```

Comment: @archie please have a look udpated answer.

Comment: Suman - thank you! it worked :) so I dont understand my error

Comment: `this.checkbox` does not refer the check box you wanted.